# Multiple Primary Keys Table - Hibernate NonUniqueObjectException

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, primary-key

I have a table with 2 primary keys (so the combination of both of them should be unique).  The schema is like this:

```
TABLE="INVOICE_LOGS"
INVOICE_NUMBER  PK  non-null
INVOICE_TYPE    PK  non-null
AMOUNT
```

When I try to persist multiple records at a time, I get this hibernate exception:

> Caused by:
>   javax.persistence.PersistenceException:
>   org.hibernate.NonUniqueObjectException:
>   a different object with the same
>   identifier value was already
>   associated with the session:
>   [...InvoiceLog#110105269]

So if I use the following code below, I get the hibernate exception above.  It works fine if I only persist one record but fails if I try to persist a collection like what I'm trying to do.

```
    List<InvoiceLog> logs = getLogs();
    for(OvercounterLogDO log: logs) {
        persist(log);
    }

    public void persist(final Object entity) {
        entityManager.persist(entity);
        entityManager.flush();
    }
```

The hibernate mapping class is below:

```
@Component(InvoiceLog.BEAN_NAME)
@Scope(BeanDefinition.SCOPE_PROTOTYPE)
@Entity
@Table(name = "INVOICE_LOGS", uniqueConstraints = {@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "INVOICE_NUMBER"),@UniqueConstraint(columnNames = "INVOICE_TYPE")} ) 
public class InvoiceLog implements java.io.Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7576525197897271909L;

    protected static final String BEAN_NAME = "invoiceLog";

    private long invoiceNumber;
    private String invoiceType;
    private Double amount;

    public InvoiceLog(){}

    public InvoiceLog(Integer invoiceNumber, String invoiceType,
            Double amount) {
        super();
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
        this.invoiceType = invoiceType;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    @Id
    @Column(name = "INVOICE_NUMBER", unique = true, nullable = false, precision = 10, scale = 0)
    public long getInvoiceNumber() {
        return invoiceNumber;
    }
    public void setInvoiceNumber(long invoiceNumber) {
        this.invoiceNumber = invoiceNumber;
    }

//  @Id
    @Column(name = "INVOICE_TYPE", nullable = false, length = 4)
    public String getInvoiceType() {
        return invoiceType;
    }
    public void setInvoiceType(String invoiceType) {
        this.invoiceType = invoiceType;
    }

    @Column(name = "AMOUNT", nullable = false, length = 12)
    public Double getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(Double amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your current mapping has a single Id, invoiceNumber, not a compound key. As such, it'll demand that the invoiceNumber be unique, not the combination you want. That's what the exception is telling you, it's noticing you're trying to save a second record with the same Id value.

You need to map the two fields as a composite key. It looks from your commenting out the second `@Id` that you were going in that direction at some point. [Here's the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#d0e2177) on methods for mapping the composite key.